# How to align equations under section name, not numbering?

Tags: equations, sectioning, fontsize

I tried aligning equations under section names, but instead they got aligned under section numberings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Integration I}
\author{LongKit}
\date{December 5, 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\section{The Euler's Number \textit{e}}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

$\begin{aligned}
e &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) ^{x} \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x!} \\
e^{x} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right) ^{n} \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Aligning]

Upper: What I get; Lower: What I want

Much Appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Please, can you put a full compilable code starting from `\documentclass`. Thus all the community can give an exahustive explanation. Regards.

Comment: Done, please have a look.

Comment: Usually the space between the section numbering and its title is fixed. This means that your left margin will change in every section. I seriously doubt you want *that*.

Comment: @campa Hi, I am agree totally with you :-) +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "twist" in your setup is that you use roman rather than arabic numerals for the section numbers. This requires setting a separate indentation amount each time `\section` is run. The following code achieves this by creating a macro called `\setmylength`, which sets the value of a length variable called `\mylength`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newlength\mylength
\newcommand\setmylength{\settowidth\mylength{\Large\bfseries\thesection\quad}}


\begin{document}

\section{Euler's Number \textit{e}}
\setmylength

\hspace{\mylength}%
$\begin{aligned}
e &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \Bigl( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \Bigr) ^{x} \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x!} \\
e^{x} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \Bigl( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \Bigr) ^{n} \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} 
\end{aligned}$

\setcounter{section}{27} % just for this example
\section{Euler's Number \textit{e}}
\setmylength

\hspace{\mylength}%
$\begin{aligned}
e &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \Bigl( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \Bigr) ^{x} \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x!} \\
e^{x} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \Bigl( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \Bigr) ^{n} \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} 
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up query: If more than one alignment point is needed, replaced the `aligned` environment with an `alginedat` environment. E.g.,

```
$\begin{alignedat}{2}
&e &&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \Bigl( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \Bigr) ^{x} \\
&  &&= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x!} \\
&e^{x} &&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \Bigl( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \Bigr) ^{n} \\
&  &&= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} 
\end{alignedat}$
```

Comment: What if I want to align the equations by the leftmost character? Such as the "E" in Euler's, "e" and "e" in e^x should be at the same vertical line. Because I realize that equations may be strange if the left side of = is very long.

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/6e31f800

Comment: @LongKit - Please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: @LongKit - What is the purpose of the material in the pastebin link? Incidentally, why did you leave off the `%` in `\hspace{\mylength}%`?

Comment: I thought ending an align then start a new one will change the align width. And I forgot to delete %.

Comment: Sorry I meant this. https://pasteboard.co/JDD9XHa.png.

Comment: Please help. I wanted to type a note for revision for myself.

Comment: @LongKit - Sorry, I don't understand your latest comment.

Comment: In your version, all four equal signs are aligned. However, when the left side is too long, there is a blank space between the left side and the equal sign [Upper figure].

I prefer aligning the equal signs in each equation independently, so that the length of the left side of equation A will not affect the position of equal sign of equation B [Lower figure].

Comment: @LongKit - It would appear that you're now looking to solve a new formatting problem that's barely related to the one you posed initially. Please post a *new* query, to ask how one might achieve the new objective.

Comment: Oh okay, I see.

Comment: I've set up a new question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574574/how-to-first-align-the-equations-under-section-names-then-align-each-equation.

Answer (score 4):

Here I have given an answer using `nccmath`, and `scrextend` packages with the enviroment

```
\begin{addmargin}.... \end{addmargin}
```

I had worked before without your MWE and I think that there are many solutions. With

`\begin{addmargin}[.5em]{1em}&<------`

you can change the parameters of the left margin of the only equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\section{The Euler's Number $e$.}
\begin{addmargin}[.5em]{1em}
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{align*}
 e &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) ^{x} \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x!} \\
e^{x} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right) ^{n} \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} 
 \end{align*}
\end{fleqn} 
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

I put another example, with `\begin{addmargin}[1em]{1em}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\section{The Euler's Number $e$.}
\begin{addmargin}[1em]{1em}
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{align*}
 e &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) ^{x} \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x!} \\
e^{x} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right) ^{n} \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} 
 \end{align*}
\end{fleqn} 
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah that helps. Thanks!

Comment: @Mico You're right :-)...I hope to switch the green mark.

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I did not see your answer when I selected the tick mark. And I didn't know that the width of the align does not increase when the number gets bigger. I'm new to LaTeX.

Comment: @LongKit But no don't worry. It is right that you should choose the answer you like from here. This is the spirit of the site. I always wish you the best.