# How to first align the equations under section names, then align each "Equation block" independently, according to the equal signs?

Tags: align

I've tried to align equations under section names and equal signs, but I found out that there is a large gap between the left side of the equation and the right side if one of the equations has a long left. In other words, one equation affects others.
[image]

The upper image is what I got, the lower image is what I want.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Just use two different align(*) environments.

Comment: Full disclosure: This query is a follow-up to an [earlier query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573691/5001).